# Extrair '_id' de objeto load_response

Tags: python-3.x, dicionário, response

Após fazer post, recebo um objeto `load_response`, no formato Dict, com a seguinte estrutura:

```
{'_content': b'{"params":{},"_id":"5a566f175ff52e02704de1aa","variables":"/dataset/5a566f175ff52e02704de1aa/variables","scenarios":"/dataset/5a566f175ff52e02704de1aa/scenarios","client_code":"test","tags":["test"]}',
 '_content_consumed': True,
 'connection': <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter at 0x111103d30>,
 'cookies': <RequestsCookieJar[]>,
 'elapsed': datetime.timedelta(0, 25, 923809),
 'encoding': 'UTF-8',
 'headers': {'Server': 'waitress', 'Content-Length': '215', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Date': 'Wed, 10 Jan 2018 19:52:29 GMT'},
 'history': [],
 'raw': <requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse at 0x113bd1240>,
 'reason': 'Created',
 'request': <PreparedRequest [POST]>,
 'status_code': 201,
 'url': 'http://localhost:8080/xfg/v2.0/dataset'}
```

Gostaria de saber como posso extrair o valor do campo "_id" desse dicionário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem, serializado como uma string de bytes, um outro objeto JSON, que é o conteúdo da chave `_content`. É fácil ver isso por que você tem a estrutura de um dicionário, e outras formatações típicas do formato JSON totalmente contídas entre os marcadores `b'` e `'`.
Então, supondo que o que você colocou na questão esteja dentro da variável `data`, você pode fazer:

```
import json
...
# data = request.json()  # Uma das formas de chegar até onde você está
...
inner_data = json.loads(data["_content"])
id = inner_data["_id"]
```

Por padrão, o json.loads do Python assume que a string de bytes está em utf-8. Alguns formulários web  e códigos antigos podem mandar a codificação como "latin1" - - nesse caso, você deve decodificar a string antes de passa-la ao `loads`:

```
inner_data = json.loads(data["_content"].decode("latin1"))
```